# Get File Size of files on Windows through Shell Script on Solaris/Unix

Tags: windows, bash, shell, unix, cmd

I am writing a Shell Script using Bash on Solaris to retrieve the Size of a remote file on a Windows Server.

```
size=$(ssh $id@$ip <Windows Prompt command to get size of file at C:\Users\KMST\Documents\log.txt>)
```

Would the above be possible? I can't find a Windows equivalent of the following unix command,

```
du KMST_GMS_UpdateLog.txt | cut -f1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for %a in ("C:\Users\KMST\Documents\log.txt") do @echo(%~za
```

**edited**

Tested (in debian) and works as

```
file=C:\\Users\\KMST\\Documents\\log.txt
size=$(ssh $id@$ip "for %a in (\"$file\") do @echo(%~za")
echo $size
if test $size -gt 100 
then
    echo "greater than 100"
fi
if [ $size -gt 100 ]
then
    echo "greater than 100"
fi
```

Comment: Do I have to enclose the above commands in anything? $(x) or ` or " or '

Comment: Would it be possible to insert a variable into the path? Eg for %a in ("$FULLPATH") do @echo(%~za

Comment: @ParkTaecyeon, sorry, I don't have a windows ssh server at hand to test, so I can't check if you need to enclose it or not. You can use any variable defined in your shell as far as you ensure it is replaced in the Solaris side and what is seen in the windows server is just a string.

Comment: I have been using, for %a in ("$FULLPATH") do @echo(%~za Unfortunately it's not working.

Comment: @ParkTaecyeon, answer updated. For me, from debian to a windows ssh server it works as posted, I'm not sure if it will work in your environment.

Comment: Thanks. I finally got a hold of servers and managed to test it as well. Don't mind if I ask another question, once I got the size as a variable in Unix, all conditional comparisons seems to fail, I don't understand why. I have tried removing tabs/spaces/newlines, but to no avail.

Comment: @ParkTaecyeon, I have tested it as shown in the answer (I've included the conditional code) and for me it is working.

Comment: Unfortunately, the conditional isn't working, it's getting a ": integer expression expected" I'm working on a Solaris server, could this be the reason why?

Comment: @ParkTaecyeon, sorry, if it is a problem in the Solaris side it is out of my knowledge. I've not touched a Solaris machine in the last 17 years. Anyway, have you tested the content of the variable? Can you use something like `echo $size | hexdump -C`?

Comment: Thanks. I got it to work. But what about files in other Drive? Eg. E:\ Where should I insert pushd/cd /d